# How to create a Protected Route with Promises

Tags: reactjs, react-router, amazon-cognito, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm using a hook to protect my routes. The problem that I'm encountering is that the call to check for the user's auth status returns a Promise, so the hook returns the default value, which is a  and then the auth status is no longer useful since we already redirected.

So how can I wait to return from the hook until the auth check is done? Here's my code:

```
export function ProtectedRoute(props){

const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
        let user = null;

        try {
            user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            if (user) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } else
            {
                setLoggedIn(false);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            setLoggedIn(false);
        }
    }
    fetchUser()
});

console.log("ProtectedRoute: returning " + loggedIn);
if (loggedIn)
    return props.component
else
    return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution...had to default to 'true' for isAuthenticated and then redirect if that wasn't the case (the Redirect seemed to be breaking the logic for me in my initial code)

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }){

const [isAuthenticated, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        let user = null;

        try {
            user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            if (user) {
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } else
            {
                setLoggedIn(false);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            setLoggedIn(false);
        }
    })();
});

return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
    />
);
```

}

Comment: And what happens if there is no server response  for 1 minute? (Or the user slows down the application manually? )  - The route gets no protection -

Comment: I'm less concerned with that since the user would not be able to do anything in that route unless he's logged in (no valid JWT tokens).

Comment: BTW, this "protection" is mostly cosmetic. The real protection is done in the backend. On another note, if your server response takes that long that the application needs to be rearchitected. Failures need to happen fast.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a new state, `loading`, and till ist `true`, just rendering a loading component:

```
    export default ProtectedRoute(props) {
    
      const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          try {
            setLoading(true);
            const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            setLoggedIn(!!user);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setLoggedIn(false);
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })();
      }, []);
    
      if(loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
        
      if (loggedIn) return props.component
    
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }}/>
  }
```

Comment: It immediately redirects since the call to Cognito takes some time, and then then component is never loaded.